# Jscript regular expression for first letter to capital and consists of two words with a single space between words

Tags: regex

hello i am trying to get a regular expression which checks whether a given string has two words with a asingle space between them and first letter should be a uppercase and length of the string is 1-20.I have my javasript in xsl file.

This is what i tried

```
/(?=.{1,20}$)\S+\s\S+/.test(peru)
```

expected output

```
Hello World:true;
my Name:false;
My name:false;
My Nameishaihellobyebye:false;
 Hello World:false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(?m)^(?=(?<I>[A-Z]{1})(?<W1>[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?<S>[ \t\r\n\v\f]{1})(?<I2>[A-Z]{1})(?<W2>[A-Za-z0-9_]+)).{0,20}(?<=(\k<I>)(\k<W1>)(\k<S>)(\k<I2>)(\k<W2>))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.If anybody is looking for the ans.This is the answer for the above question.

```
if(!/(?=.{0,20}$)[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(peru)){                                   
document.getElementById("eredit").innerHTML="1.Value entered in the Name field is invalid";
return false;
}
```

Here peru in my program consists of the string u want to match with.And eredit is id of my paragram where i want to print the error message.Hope it helps anyone.